# Combine Mysql and Sphinx Queries?

Tags: mysql, optimization, sphinx

I have a very efficient Sphinx query working on a table. However part of the query unfortunatley requires a large 'OR' statement consisting of 100s of options. Sphinx chokes on

`@(field) (1|2|..|800)`

pretty badly taking as long as one minute while the same pipe query in Mysql takes <1 second whether doing

`field in (1,2,..,800`

or even

`Field =1 or Field=2 or Field=... or Field=800`.

Is there a way to combine both in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sphinx can do `in(..)` queries on ATTRIBUTEs.

Probably not as efficiently as mysql (at least if indexed column)

```
sphinxQL> SELECT * FROM index WHERE MATCH('...') AND attrib IN (1,2,...)
```

Comment: I'm assuming that will be more efficient than doing the `@(field) (1|2|...)`?  I am trying to test here but while `attribname = '1'` works `attribname in ('1',2',...)` gives me the error "[Err] 1064 - sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected QUOTED_STRING, expecting CONST_INT or '-' near ''1','2')'"

Comment: I think I need to change my attrib type I will report back sorry.

Comment: Once I fixed attr type works like a charm. For reference sake when I put the 2000 IDs in the Match as `@(Field) 1|2|...|2000` took two minutes, when I did as `and attribname in (1,2,...,2000) took .126 seconds. Faster in fact then the Mysql  query...

Answer (score 0):

If attrib is a `VARCHAR`, then this is best for MySQL:

```
 WHERE attrib IN ('1', '2', ...)
```

If it is numeric, then this is best for MySQL:

```
 WHERE attrib IN (1, 2, ...)
```

Note that having the constant be the wrong type can lead to serious inefficiency.